# How do you comment out an XML node using Powershell 3.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to comment out an XML node in a configuration file using Powershell 3.0.

For instance, if this is my `config.xml` file:

```
<node>
    <foo type="bar" />
</node>
```

I would like my script to change the file to this:

```
<node>
    <!-- <foo type="bar" /> -->
</node>
```

I am looking to do this using Powershell 3.0's native XML/XPATH functionality, and not match/regex-based string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CreateComment()` to create a new comment node containing the existing node's XML, then remove the existing:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<node>
    <foo type="bar" />
</node>
'@

# Find all <foo> nodes with type="bar"
foreach($node in $xml.SelectNodes('//foo[@type="bar"]')){
  # Create new comment node
  $newComment = $xml.CreateComment($node.OuterXml)

  # Add as sibling to existing node
  $node.ParentNode.InsertBefore($newComment, $node) |Out-Null

  # Remove existing node
  $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node) |Out-Null
}

# Export/save $xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mathias!   I had an extremely hard time trying to find detailed information on type accelerators (i.e. `[xml]`) in Powershell 3.0.  I'll eventually need a way to *uncomment* nodes - hoping to find this information on my own.